# how do i rename the video file after i export it?

Tags: video

I downloaded some videos to my android tablet from drop box. I then edited the videos together as one file and am ready to upload to a business site which the files are required to be named a specific way.  I cannot figure out how to rename the the completed file and meet the requirements of the site. When I click on the file in my video folder the only option I get is to delete the file. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use another file manager application like ES file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

either try another file explorer if you are not familiar with the default one (usually either a "right click" or long hold to get the file rename option).

my personal favorite since it is double-windowed is total commander or you can try that ES file explorer (ad-supported maybe)...